# C++: Calculate probability percentage during each iteration

Tags: c++

Can't seem to get this to work. The idea is to calculate the percentage of heads and tails after each count, accumulating after each iteration. Except I keep getting **nan%** for my calculations. Anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

```
void flipCoin(time_t seconds, int flipCount){
    vector<int> flips;
    float headCount = 0;
    float tailCount = 0;
    double headProbability = double((headCount/(headCount + tailCount))*100);
    double tailProbability = double((tailCount/(headCount + tailCount))*100);

    for (int i=0; i < flipCount; i++) {
        int flip = rand() % (HEADS - TAILS + 1) + TAILS;
        flips.push_back(flip);
        if (flips[i] == 1) {
            tailCount++;
            cout << "Tail Percent: " << tailProbability << "%" << endl;
        }else{
            headCount++;
            cout << "Head Percent: " << headProbability << "%" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cast `headCount` to a `double`. What output do you get?

Comment: Does "headCount + tailCount" ever == zero?  If so: BZZZZZ!  That's where you get "Not a Number"!  Solution?  Make sure your code never attempts to divide by zero ;)  In other words, increment headCount and/or tailCount *BEFORE* you compute "probability".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to do this

```
void flipCoin(time_t seconds, int flipCount){
    vector<int> flips;
    float headCount = 0;
    float tailCount = 0;
    double headProbability = 0;
    double tailProbability = 0;

    for (int i=0; i < flipCount; i++) {
        int flip = rand() % (HEADS - TAILS + 1) + TAILS;
        flips.push_back(flip);
        if (flips[i] == 1) {
            tailCount++;
            tailProbability = double((tailCount/(headCount + tailCount))*100);
            cout << "Tail Percent: " << tailProbability << "%" << endl;
        }else{
            headCount++;
            headProbability = double((headCount/(headCount + tailCount))*100);
            cout << "Head Percent: " << headProbability << "%" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, if all you want to do is print the percentages, you dont need tailProbability or headProbablity. You can directly print the calculations.

EDIT : You can also replace headCount + tailCount with i+1 . But that could cause problems if you change the function later on.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem lies in the fact that you only ever calculate `headProbability` and `tailProbability` once - and when you do calculate them, it will evaluate to `0 / 0`.

```
float headCount = 0;
float tailCount = 0;
// Both are 0, end up as 0/0
double headProbability = double((headCount/(headCount + tailCount))*100);  
double tailProbability = double((tailCount/(headCount + tailCount))*100);

//Never recalculated in the loop
```

To fix this, simply define them as 0 initially, and then recalculate them in the loop. You also don't seem to need a `vector` here, as you only need to keep track of the count, not the result of every flip:

```
double headProbability = 0;
double tailProbability = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < flipCount; ++i) {
    int flip = rand() % (HEAS - TAIL + 1) + TAILS; //This could be simplified
    if(flip == 1) {
        ++tailCount;
        //Recalculate tailProbability
    } else { 
       //Etc...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`nan` means Not a number. You got it because you divide by 0.

Your code calcul probabilities just one time, before any flip coin.
You need to put calculs in the loop for recalculate probabilities after each iteration.

```
void flipCoin(time_t seconds, int flipCount){
    vector<int> flips;
    float headCount = 0;
    float tailCount = 0;
    double headProbability;
    double tailProbability;

    for (int i=0; i < flipCount; i++) {
        int flip = rand() % (HEADS - TAILS + 1) + TAILS;
        flips.push_back(flip);

        headProbability = double((headCount/(headCount + tailCount))*100);
        tailProbability = double((tailCount/(headCount + tailCount))*100);

        if (flips[i] == 1) {
            tailCount++;
            cout << "Tail Percent: " << tailProbability << "%" << endl;
        }else{
            headCount++;
            cout << "Head Percent: " << headProbability << "%" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```